# Event Sourcing, Conflict between two services in processing same event

Tags: microservices, cqrs, event-sourcing

I started learning about event sourcing and CQRS, but i didn't get something right.

If i have two services that both process the same event but in different ways (for example in booking sample, one service checks timeslot and another checks user credit), and one of them accepts the event but the other one doesn't, what should the system do?

How should the services know if other services have accepted or declined the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, each of these processors will calculate something regarding of the others result.

What you can do for example, is have another service, upstream, that would collect the results of those services, aggregate them, and when it has all the processing results for an event, it can do whatever you want. It knows that processes accepted, what processes didn't, and based on the logic of your system decide what to do.

Example:

`BookingService` emits event:

```
{
    "bookingId": 123,
    "creditCardDetails": ...,
    "timeslot": ...
}
```

`CreditCardService` receives and emits:

```
{
    "service": "CreditCardService",
    "bookingId": 123,
    "accepted": false,
}
```

`TimeslotService` receives and emits:

```
{
    "service": "TimeslotService",
    "bookingId": 123,
    "accepted": true,
}
```

And in the `BookingProcessingAggregatorService` you get all the responses and react accordingly.

I've created an example using Typescript and RxJS to simulate a messaging system with events,
Hope this is clear enough (it was nice to write it anyhow, so it might as well help you ):

https://rxjs-nexjv8.stackblitz.io

Comment: thanks for your answer. the problem with this approach for me was that the service which accepted the event has changed it's materialized view. so the aggregator service should undo it if other service didn't approve the event somehow. it may result in very complex situations i think as all services should support undoing events.

Comment: undoing becomes more complex if another event was reached the service before the undoing happened.

Comment: So you have to separate action from validation. Desperate the validation and action, and the aggregator, which then becomes like a main validation services, passes on the fact that validation has passed to the services, and only then will they do what they can.

Comment: And in cases where you can’t do that so simply, you do have to think of some way to do a rollback or prevent the side effect from getting out of the system.

Comment: This is a good resource to read up on this kinda stuff: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/

Answer (score 3):

At a high level: when you have a distributed system, the different components in the system share information by passing messages.  When your scheduling service wants to let you know that the time slot you requested has been reserved for you, it does that by sending you a message.

When you want to know whats going on somewhere else, you look at the messages you have received.

> How should the services know if other services have accepted or declined the event?

An important thing to understand is that services should never be *declining* events.  `ApprovalRequested` is describes a thing that happened, and the subscribing service cannot make it unhappen.

What will usually happen is that the subscriber will receive `ApprovalRequested`, update its own local data, and then either emit `ApprovalGranted` or `ApprovalDeclined` as appropriate.

In your case, you have a subscriber that is going to emit either an approval or rejection of the time slot, and another subscriber that is going to emit either an approval or rejection of the credit check.

Somewhere else, we have a state machine, that is doing the bookkeeping of all of these events to know whether the booking was successful or not.

Rinat Abdullin's essay on [process managers](https://abdullin.com/post/ddd-evolving-business-processes-a-la-lokad/) may help.